# C++: how to most elegantly minimize instance copying in this case?

Tags: c++

I have a class `Heavy` that is time-consuming to copy. And there is a non-static method `Heavy Heavy::create()`, which creates another instance of `Heavy`.

Now, I have an instance `a` of `Heavy` and I want to do something like:

```
if(condition(a)) {
  Heavy b = a.create();
  // -- do a lot of stuff with b --
} else {
  // -- do the same stuff with a --
}
```

Now I wonder what is the most elegant way to separate the "do some stuff" from the condition. Several alternatives, which are all somewhat strange:

A) This needs to copy the object once when not optimized away by the complier:

```
Heavy *b, tmp;
if(condition(a)) {
  tmp = a.create();
  b = &tmp;
} else {
  b = &a;
}
// -- do stuff with *b --
```

B) I could also make the `create` function return a pointer to a non-temporary instance: `Heavy *Heavy::create()`. Then, the following needs an additional `bool` (or two calls to `condition(a)`):

```
Heavy *b;
bool newInstance = condition(a);
if(newInstance) {
  b = a.create();
} else {
  b = &a;
}
// -- do stuff with *b --
if(newInstance) {
  delete b;
}
```

More elegant ideas?
Clearly, one could also put the "do some stuff" into a separate function, but otherwise?

Comment: hmmm... [move semantics](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/rvalue-references-and-move-semantics-in-c++11.html)?

Comment: Is return value of `a.create();` a pointer? Then `tmp` should be pointer also.

Comment: "Clearly, one could also put the "do some stuff" into a separate function" -- actually, I'd probably do it that way. Rule of thumb: if something can be compartmentalized into a separate function, it probably should be.

Comment: I agree: The "elegant" way is the function `doSomeStuff(Heavy const &);` alas `condition(a) ? doSomeStuff(a.create()) : doSomeStuff(a);` or something  ;)

Comment: `Heavy` is expensive to copy. Could you clarify whether it is also expensive to move?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Expanding on Ami Tavory's answer a bit, you could actually use an immediately-invoked lambda:

```
[](const Heavy& h) {
    // Do stuff with a or b
}(condition(a) ? a.create() : a);
```

Note that, if you want it to work more like a normal if block (letting you access outside local variables and so on), you should probably use `[&]` at the start rather than `[]`.

Also, it won't work if you need to modify `a`, since dropping the `const` here will cause it to not compile.

Comment: I'm afraid this also has hidden copies when the condition is false.

Comment: How so? It's passing `a` by reference.

Comment: I think this quote from the standard applies: "The second and third operands have the same type; the result is of that type. If the operands have
class type, the result is a prvalue temporary of the result type, which is copy-initialized from either
the second operand or the third operand depending on the value of the first operand." You can test this using a class which logs all calls to its copy constructor/assignment operator.

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand what that means, but more important is... can it be fixed?

Comment: We want the `const&` to extend the lifetime of the temporary `a.create()` when the condition is true. But when the condition is false, it should just reference `a`. This behaviour is impossible from a `const&` - it would need to remember whether or not to destruct the object when the reference goes out of scope. But it compiles! That's because the `?:` operator copy-initializes a temporary `Heavy` from either `a.create()` or `a`, and passes *the temporary* by `const&` to the lambda. In the case where the condition is false, this results in copying `a`.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I can't think of any way to fix it though; I don't think taking an r-value reference as the parameter would help.

Answer (score 7):

I'd say that if you have

```
// -- do a lot of stuff with b --
...
// -- do the same stuff with a --
```

then the most readable thing would be to factor out "do a lot of stuff" to a function that takes a `Heavy` reference, and call it either with one or the other.

In case you don't think its worth a named function, you can use a lambda:

```
auto do_lots_of_stuff = [](Heavy &h){
    // Doing stuff
};
```

and then immediately use

```
if(condition(a)) {
    auto b = a.create();
    do_lots_of_stuff(b);
}
else
    do_lots_of_stuff(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the stuff to be done doesn't modify the Heavy, then this *seems* cleanest:

```
const Heavy &h = condition(a) ? a.create() : a;

// do stuff with h
```

But there is actually a copy hiding in here - if `condition(a)` is false, then `a` will be copied into a temporary. If `condition(a)` is true, then there is no such problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough of context exposed to give any advices. Also consider you could encounter an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.

But Here are few ideas anyway.

**By the way**

The code you've presented is most likely [smells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell):

- You are using raw pointers. Leaks and frustration are imminent. Use smart pointers.
- There is no clear ownership of the result of `create()`. Enforce it by using smart pointers.
- Non static method creates another object. Is this kind of `clone()`? Then sometimes you could use copy (or move) constructor instead.
- `A` is out of question, as `tmp` goes out of scope leaving you with dangling pointer and undefined behavior

**Possible refactoring by wrapping inside-out**

As far as I understand, you have a "condition" that depends only on `Heavy a` and `do_stuff` that accepts pointer to heavy.

It seems like that code could be easily be responsibility of `Heavy`, so you could refactor that code into `Heavy`, effectively transforming an explicit parameter to `this`:

- Move condition inside a method:

  ```
  bool Heavy::is_condition_true() const;
  ```
- Move `do_stuff` inside a method:

  ```
  void Heavy:do_stuff();
  ```

This will transform your `B` into:

```
Heavy *b;
if(a.is_condition_true()) {
   b = a.create();
} else {
   b = &a;
}

b->do_stuff();
```

There is obviously a conditional memory leak now. 
Further refactoring could include moving conditional inside `do_stuff()`, as all you need is `this` pointer, transforming user code to:

```
a.do_stuff();
```

And your code to:

```
void do_stuff() {
    Heavy* b;
    if(is_condition_true()) {
       b = a.create();
    } else {
       b = this;
    }

    b->do_stuff_implementation();
}
```

Now this could allow you to get rid of cloning, and thus memory allocation and ownership, and possibly to simplify your code and making it shine. Or not ;)

**Possible refactoring by creating a factory**

If you really need this `create` method, consider moving it into a free function or a factory class:

```
 std::shared_ptr<Heavy> createHeavy(...);

 class HeavyFactory {
 public:
     std::shared_ptr<Heavy> create(...);
 };
```

**Possible refactoring by defining separate types**

If `a` and `b` undergo different processing inside `do_stuff` (a good sign of it are conditionals inside this function), that could mean that they are different types. In this case, you could make them different classes with different methods and change your conditional expression accordingly.

<sub>P.S. Code above only looks like C++, in reality it is a pseudo-code and it was written in notepad and has never been compiled.</sub>

Comment: don't cite the XY problem unnecessarily

Comment: @JasonS Why do you think it is unnecessary here? We are clearly solving a problem of one of the solution, not the problem itself.

Comment: You can't replace `clone()` with a copy/move constructor in the presence of polymorphism - the point of `clone()` is that it copies the derived class even when you only have a pointer to the base.

Comment: because we don't know the OP's situation; no matter how misguided we think he/she is, the OP knows the full story, and until we do, we should not pass judgement. Be factual.

Comment: @JasonS That was never my intention to judge. I've changed the formulation to make it more like advice or guidance. Thank you.

Comment: @celticminstrel Valid point, thank you, I've changed the formulation too. However, I don't think we are dealing with polymorphism here, as `create()` in option `A` returns the clone by value.

Answer (score 0):

Although this might not be the simplest of answers, it does fulfil the stated goal of not making a separate function for `do_lots_of_stuff`.

First put this code in a header

```
template <typename T>
class Extend
{
    struct Extender
    {
        virtual ~Extender() {}
        virtual T *get()=0;
    };

    struct RValueRefExtender : Extender
    {
        T t;
        RValueRefExtender(T &&t_) : t(std::move(t_)) {}
        T *get() {return &t;}
    };

    struct RefExtender : Extender
    {
        T &t;
        RefExtender(T &t_) : t(t_) {}
        T *get() {return &t;}
    };

    std::unique_ptr<Extender> e;

public:
    Extend(T  &t) : e(new       RefExtender(          t )) {}
    Extend(T &&t) : e(new RValueRefExtender(std::move(t))) {}
    T *operator*()  const {return e->get();}
    T *operator->() const {return e->get();}
};

template <typename T>
auto extend(T &&t) {return Extend<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>(std::forward<T>(t));}

#define heavy_conditional(c, l, r) (c ? extend(l) : extend(r))
```

Then usage is as simple as

```
auto h = heavy_conditional(condition(a), a, a.create());

// Do lots of stuff with h. Treat h as if a pointer, e.g.
h->print();
dump(*h);
```

This method will not silently call the copy constructor of Heavy, unlike my previous answer.

---

How it works: the `extend` function takes an expression, and returns an `Extend` object which decides whether or not the expression's lifetime needs extending, and takes care of destructing it if so (similar to example B in your question).

By the way, never do this. It's just an example that does the job without using a separate function. For what you *should* do, see Ami Tavory's answer.